# Adding an option to choicebox in SharePoint, c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to add an option to choicebox named 'yyy' in all lists called 'xxx'. My code prints chosen option from choicebox for every list (I guess so).
I was trying to do field.GetFieldValueAsText(???) on my 'yyy' field (in other words my choicebox) but I don't know what should I pass as an argument to that method.
Anyone has any idea how to solve this out?
Thanks in advance.

```
SPSite mainSite = new SPSite(path);
SPWebCollection webColl = mainSite.AllWebs;

foreach (SPWeb web in webColl)
{
     SPListCollection listColl = web.Lists;
     foreach (SPList list in listColl)
     {
          if (list.Title.Equals("xxx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
          {                        
               SPFieldCollection fields = list.Fields; 

               foreach (SPField field in fields)
               {
                    if (field.Title.Equals("yyy", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                         foreach (SPItem item in items)
                                Console.WriteLine(item["yyy"]);               

                    }
               }


          }
     }

}
```

Comment: I found SPFieldChoice class wich allows me to read ChoiceBox content easily.